# How to implement push notification in KaiOS app

Tags: kaios

I am trying to implement push notification in KaiOS app. I simply follow below links.

- [W3C Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/)
- [Push API introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API)
- [Service Worker Cookbook - Web Push Payload](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_service-worker_doc.html)

After follow all links the push is working in browser but not in KaiOS app.
If anybody have any sample code or documents please share.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: after many tries implemented successfully.

Comment: Could you please share the solution.

Comment: @Rohit I am also stuck in the same situation from. several days, if you can share your code or method you implemented it will be very helpful to us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) First, add this permission in `manifest.webapp`

```
    "permissions": {
          "serviceWorker":{
             "description": "required for handle push."
          },
          "push":{
             "description": "New update push."
          },
          "desktop-notification": {
             "description": "New content update notification for the user."
          }
       }
```

2) service worker file `sw.js` code

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification('My Push', {
            body: 'Push Activated',
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
    self.clients.claim();
});
```

3) Add service worker on app start

```
registerSW : function() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js').then(function(reg) {
            console.log('Service Worker Registered!', reg);
            reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(sub) {
                if (sub === null) {

                } else {
                    console.log('Subscription object: ', sub);
                }
            });
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log('SW reg failed');
        });
    }
}
```

4) Call service worker by any dom element like button

```
registerServiceWorker: function() {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
            if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {

                    reg.pushManager.subscribe({
                        userVisibleOnly: true
                    }).then(function(sub) {
                        console.log('Endpoint URL: ', sub.endpoint);

                    }).catch(function(e) {
                        if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
                            console.warn('Permission for notifications was denied');
                        } else {
                            console.error('Unable to subscribe to push', e);
                        }
                    });
                })
            }
        }
    });
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem as this, but I followed this simple web push notification method,

https://medium.com/@seladir/how-to-implement-web-push-notifications-in-your-node-react-app-9bed79b53f34

as well as I fixed that issue and now It work properly. please don't forget to add permissions like below into the `manifest.webapp` file.

```
"permissions": {
    "serviceworker": {
        "description": "Needed for assocating service worker"
    },
    "desktop-notification": {
        "description": "Needed for creating system notifications."
    },
    "notifications": {},
    "push": {
        "description": "Required for being updated with new goals in soccer matches"
    },
    "geolocation": {
        "description": "Marking out user location"
    },
    "alarms": {
        "description": "Scheduling alarms"
    }
},
```

and as well as please refer this kaios documention for run the applicaion on kaios device.

https://developer.kaiostech.com/getting-started/build-your-first-hosted-app/pwa-to-hosted-app

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)